# How can I bind a text box to a property in a child object of the current item?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using WinForms, I have a binding source with a list of Question objects as it's the data source. Each of those Question objects has (among other things) a child object called 'varname'. varname has a string property VarLabel.

I want the form to display one question at a time and the user can move through it with the binding navigator.

This works fine until I try adding a text box to show the VarLabel.

I tried binding the controls of the form in the constructor like this:

```
public Form1 ()
{
   CurrentSurvey = GetSurveyInfo(); // get from database  
   // check for null survey etc.  
   InitializeComponent();  
   bs = new BindingSource
   {
      DataSource = CurrentSurvey.Questions
   };  
   txtVarLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "varname.VarLabel");
   // set other control bindings which work fine, but they are properties of the current question 
   // object
}
```

None of the objects are null, I double-checked. All the properties are public auto-properties.

Am I binding child properties incorrectly?

EDIT: Class definitions

varname is  a VariableName object defined as:

```
public class VariableName
{
    public string VarName { get; set; }
    public string refVarName { get; set; }
    public string VarLabel { get; set; }
    public DomainLabel Domain { get; set; }
    public TopicLabel Topic { get; set; }
    public ContentLabel Content { get; set; }
    public ProductLabel Product { get; set; }
}
```

Questions is a BindingList of SurveyQuestion objects containing a VariableName property.

```
public class SurveyQuestion
{
    public VariableName Varname { get; set; }
    // many other properties
}
```

Framework version is 4.6.1

Comment: I should add the error I get after the form loads is that it "cannot bind to the property or column VarLabel on the datasource"

Comment: Since `txtVarLabel` is a TextBox, the Binding should work as it is. Can you post the structure definition of your class and the actual type of `CurrentSurvey.Questions`? The Framework version in use, too. If you use an older Framework, you can add a second BindingSource to the `varname` class and use as DataSource the BindingSource that holds the main class object List(?).

Comment: There: `txtVarLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "varname.VarLabel"); =>`  `varname` doesn't match the property name: `SurveyQuestion.Varname` (capital `V`)

Comment: I've fixed this but get the same error. Strangely, if I move these properties "up" a level to the SurveyQuestion object, I can bind, for example, a combo box's selected value to Domain.ID. Is there something different about string properties ?

Comment: No, nothing. I've tested it in Framework 4.6.1 (just to be sure I didn't forget about something specific to this framework) and it works as expected; when the names of the properties are respected, of course. Add a Binding like this: `txtVarLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Varname.VarLabel", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));`, assuming `bs` is a BindingSource.

Comment: So I changed the name of the property Varname to Test just to see and it worked. Why would the name of it matter? The SurveyQuestion object did have other properties with similar names (I'm still cleaning it up) but why would that matter? They all had different capitalization.

Comment: The Property value you're binding is `SurveyQuestion.Varname.VarLabel`. The  names of properties are case-sensitive.

Comment: As a suggestion, you should use more *distinctive* names. `VariableName` has a `VarName` property and this name is almost identical to the one used in the `SurveyQuestion` class (`Varname`). This can create *confusion*.

Comment: Yes I am in the process of changing the names. But shouldn't the binding still work regardless of the confusing names? Or is it the compiler that is getting confused?

Comment: *Confusing* is referred to humans. The compiler doesn't get *confused*. It tries to bind a property that doesn't exist: `varname != VarName != Varname`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the binding to work by renaming the nested property and at Jimi's suggestion used more distinctive names for all properties involved. I'm still not sure why the names mattered, as far as I could tell I was binding with the correct path to the property, with correct capitalization and everything.